# Bigcommerce fraud flag in API?

Tags: bigcommerce

On some orders bigcommerce shows a fraud flag.

We have an order management system.

How can we get that flag via the API so that we can see it in our order management system?

Answer (score 1):

The fraud flag appears on an order when the GEO_IP location of the customer and the billing address. If these two locations don't match countries, the flag appears within the control panel.

This isn't available as a true/false value in the API, but you can do the same match to obtain this information or use a third party app like [Subuno](http://www.subuno.com/)